# Get Server Path of an Image by Product ID - Magento 1.8

Tags: php, codeigniter, magento

I have a CI project and a Magento Project on same server.

I want to periodically import Magento products into my CI website.

Everything is working perfectly, I am currently able to import each thing from Magento to my CI website.

BUT, ***how do I get physical/server paths of images of magento product?*** I want to copy those image files to my CI project.

Here is relative line I am loading product with

```
$product = $simpleProduct->getData()
```

And this is Image related part of what I get in return. look at `file` key, its not actuall server path.

```
 "media_gallery":{  
     "images":[  
        {  
           "value_id":"6",
           "file":"\/2\/-\/2-2.jpg",
           "label":"",
           "position":"1",
           "disabled":"0",
           "label_default":null,
           "position_default":"1",
           "disabled_default":"0"
        },
        {  
           "value_id":"5",
           "file":"\/2\/_\/2.jpg",
           "label":"",
           "position":"2",
           "disabled":"0",
           "label_default":null,
           "position_default":"2",
           "disabled_default":"0"
        }
     ],
     "values":[  

     ]
  },
```

**PS**
I dont want browser path of an image like this http://www.website/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/2/-/image_name_here.jpg

I want server path.

Comment: 1codeigniter` or `magento`?

Comment: As I said Magento and CI project are on same server, so yes I have access to Magento ...  as you see I am using ` $simpleProduct->getData()` to load product ... hence I need solution in Magento ...

Comment: I have initialized magento using `require_once("../app/Mage.php");`

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can get this by using this code 
for cache images

```
foreach ($_product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) {
        echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image', $image->getFile());
    }
```

for without cache original images

```
foreach ($_product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) {

        echo Mage::getUrl('media').'catalog/'.'product'.$image->getFile().'<br>';
    }
```

Comment: I guess it returns only 1 image. I want all images of a product

Answer (score 0):

A script I made which extracts information about a product using its sku :

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['productId']))
{
getImage($_GET['productId']);
}
else{
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found', true, 404);
    echo "404 Not found";
    die();
}
function getImage($product)
{
    @ob_start();
    @session_start();

    //for order update
    include 'app/Mage.php';
    Mage::app('default');
    $product_id = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getIdBySku( $product );
    $cProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $cProduct->load($product_id);
    $productInfo = Array(
    'name' => $cProduct->getImageUrl(),
    'url' => $cProduct->getUrlPath(),
    'prodId' => $product_id,
    'prodName' => $cProduct->getName(),
    'prodPrice' => round($cProduct->getFinalPrice(),2),
    'currency' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol()
    ); 
    echo json_encode($productInfo); 
}


?>
```

However it will only fetch you the base url of the image not everything